# What is the purpose of using WHERE COLUMN like '%[_][01][7812]' in SQL statements?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

What is the purpose of using `WHERE COLUMN like '%[_][01][7812]'` in SQL statements?

I get some result, but don't know how to use properly.

I see that it is searching through the base, but I don't understand the pattern.

Comment: To get columns that match that `like` pattern.  In MySQL, that would be very few columns, because it does not recognize special characters such as `[`.

Comment: Yes, but in my column i don't have [] characters. its like some code looking like   TA01_55_77,
and like 50 of them different over pk. So i see query like this.
select column1 ,* from table1 where column2 = 'AA',
and (column3 like '%[_][01][5234][_]%' or sifra like '%[_][01][5234]')

So what is the reason using this kind of query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Like` selects strings similar to a pattern. The pattern you're looking at uses several wildcards, which you can review here: https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_wildcards.asp

Briefly, the query seems to ba matching any row where `COLUMN` ends in an _ then a 0 or a 1, then a 7,8,1, or 2. (So it would match 'blah_07' but not 'blah_81', 'blah_0172', or 'blah18')

Answer (score 0):

First thing as you might be aware that where clause is used for filtering rows.
In your case (Where column Like `%[_][01][7812]`) Means find the column ending with `[_][01][7812]`  and there could be anything place of %

Comment: Thanks, i figure out that one, so [] is for positions of number that we are searching. so if we have [][][]   thats three positions, and u can put like 1-3 (number from 1 to 3, and second position find me.. like 4-5 (all number from 4-5, = 45) etc..

Answer (score 0):

Although you've tagged your post MySQL, that code seems unlikely to have been written for it. That `LIKE` pattern, to me, resembles [Microsoft SQL Server's variation on the syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql), where it would match anything ending with an underscore followed by a zero or a one, followed by a 7, an 8 a 1 or a 2.

So your example 'TA01_55_77' would not match, but 'TA01_55_18' would, as would 'GZ01_55_07'

(In SQL Server, enclosing a wildcard character like '_' in square brackets escapes it, turning it into a literal underscore.)

Of course, there may be other RDBMSes with similar syntax, but what you've presented doesn't seem like it would work on the data you've got if running in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare 
@searchString varchar(50) = '[_][01][7812]', 
@testString varchar(50) = 'BeginningOfString' + '[_][01][7812]' + 'EndofString'
select CHARINDEX(@searchString, @testString), @testString, LEN(@testString) as [totalLength]

set @testString = '[_][01][7812]' + 'EndofString'
select CHARINDEX(@searchString, @testString), @testString, LEN(@testString) as [totalLength]


set @testString = 'BeginningOfString' + '[_][01][7812]'
select CHARINDEX(@searchString, @testString), @testString, LEN(@testString) as [totalLength]
```